# add "compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1" lead to conflict

Tags: java, android

add "compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1" lead to conflict:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/v4/hardware/display/DisplayManagerCompat$JellybeanMr1Impl.class

How to deal with it?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to exclude the dependency.

```
compile('compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

The reason for this error is that your project and butterknife both depend on the android support library, but the versions used are out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

As Modge answered, it has a conflict when compiling the butterknife library on the grade file. However, you must exclude the **support-compat** module in order to avoid the conflict. You may define your dependencies as follows.

```
dependencies {
...
    // Support version library may differ from yours
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile ('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-compat'
    }
... 
}
```